# Проверка интернет соединения. Java

Tags: java

Пишу программу для ПК. Нужен скрипт проверки интернет соединения, который бы подходил для всех ОС, которые поддерживает java

Comment: На Java скрипты не пишут.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean noIronCurtainYet = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 })
                                      .isReachable(3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Например можно вот так проверять доступность по url.

```
public static boolean checkConnectionUrl(String url)  {
    try {
        URL siteURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL
                .openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        return connection.getResponseCode() == 200;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e, e.fillInStackTrace());
        return false;
    }
}
```